# Remove elements from Date Format String using a Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex, date-formatting

I want to remove elements a supplied Date Format String - for example convert the format "dd/MM/yyyy" to "MM/yyyy" by removing any non-M/y element.

What I'm trying to do is create a localised month/year format based on the existing day/month/year format provided for the Locale.

I've done this using regular expressions, but the solution seems longer than I'd expect.

An example is below:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
 System.out.println(filterDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", 'M', 'y'));
 System.out.println(filterDateFormat("MM/yyyy/dd", 'M', 'y'));
 System.out.println(filterDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd", 'M', 'y'));
}

/**
 * Removes {@code charsToRetain} from {@code format}, including any redundant
 * separators.
 */
private static String filterDateFormat(final String format, final char...charsToRetain) {
 // Match e.g. "ddd-"
 final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[" + new String(charsToRetain) + "]+\\p{Punct}?");
 final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(format);

 final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

 while (matcher.find()) {
  // Append each match
  builder.append(matcher.group());
 }

 // If the last match is "mmm-", remove the trailing punctuation symbol
 return builder.toString().replaceFirst("\\p{Punct}$", "");
}
```

Comment: How long would you expect the solution to be? How flexible would it have to be, i.e. would "crazy" formats like `"MM/yy - MM"` be allowed?

Comment: @Thomas great question! It would be great if it did - but I think it's unlikely it would need to.

Comment: I do not think there is a much *shorter* method to do this. There are a lot of ways to solve this, but I am pretty sure there is no "clean" way in 2 lines of code or so. Specific problems will need specific solutions and those are rarely pretty.

Comment: @Link19 That wont work if you replace the first or last part. E.g. after replacing the days in`dd/MM/yyyy` no duplicate `/` is created. also this would also remove the duplicate characters required for the date format, resulting in `/M/y`.

Comment: As TA already stated, a much shorter solution might actually not be better. Since Java doesn't have negative regexes (i.e. "match anything that matches this pattern") you'd need to come up with an appropriate inverse version of such a regex. That might be quite cumbersome and not actually be better or even more safe. You could also have a look at the `String.replaceAll()` method (or yet better `Matcher.replaceAll()` which is used by the former) and you'll see that a similar problem (replacing things via regex) is solved in a similar amount of code.

Comment: @Jakg Would you like a fairly short regex solution that doesn't take parameters (i.e., hardcoded for M and y)?

Comment: @Avi I would be interested to see that.

Comment: @Jakg The solution is short, the explanation long :)

Comment: To be honest, I'd just construct a `Date`/`Instance` object with the input and format the result. It may not be regex, but it's going to be much easier to read and manage. This is assuming you have a fairly consistent input format though. Java should be able to handle those localized formats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try a solution for the following date format strings:

```
String[] formatStrings = { "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", 
                           "MM/yyyy/dd", 
                           "yyyy-MMM-dd", 
                           "MM/yy - yy/dd", 
                           "yyabbadabbadooMM" };
```

The following will analyze strings for a match, then print the first group of the match.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
for(String formatStr : formatStrings) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(formatStr);
    if(m.matches()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Didn't match!");
    }
}
```

Now, there are two separate regular expressions I've tried. First:

```
final String REGEX = "(?:[^My]*)([My]+[^\\w]*[My]+)(?:[^My]*)";
```

With program output:

> MM/yyyy
>   MM/yyyy
>   yyyy-MMM
>   Didn't match!
>   Didn't match!

Second:

```
final String REGEX = "(?:[^My]*)((?:[My]+[^\\w]*)+[My]+)(?:[^My]*)";
```

With program output:

> MM/yyyy
>   MM/yyyy
>   yyyy-MMM
>   MM/yy - yy
>   Didn't match!

Now, let's see what the first regex actually matches to:

```
(?:[^My]*)([My]+[^\\w]*[My]+)(?:[^My]*) First regex =
(?:[^My]*)                              Any amount of non-Ms and non-ys (non-capturing)
          ([My]+                        followed by one or more Ms and ys
                [^\\w]*                 optionally separated by non-word characters
                                        (implying they are also not Ms or ys)
                       [My]+)           followed by one or more Ms and ys
                             (?:[^My]*) finished by any number of non-Ms and non-ys
                                        (non-capturing)
```

What this means is that at least 2 M/ys are required to match the regex, although you should be careful that something like MM-dd or yy-DD will match as well, because they have two M-or-y regions 1 character long. You can avoid getting into trouble here by just keeping a sanity check on your date format string, such as:

```
if(formatStr.contains('y') && formatStr.contains('M') && m.matches())
{
    String yMString = m.group(1);
    ... // other logic
}
```

As for the second regex, here's what it means:

```
(?:[^My]*)((?:[My]+[^\\w]*)+[My]+)(?:[^My]*) Second regex =
(?:[^My]*)                                   Any amount of non-Ms and non-ys 
                                             (non-capturing)
          (                      )           followed by
           (?:[My]+       )+[My]+            at least two text segments consisting of
                                             one or more Ms or ys, where each segment is
                   [^\\w]*                   optionally separated by non-word characters
                                  (?:[^My]*) finished by any number of non-Ms and non-ys
                                             (non-capturing)
```

This regex will match a slightly broader series of strings, but it still requires that any separations between Ms and ys be non-words (`[^a-zA-Z_0-9]`). Additionally, keep in mind that this regex will still match "yy", "MM", or similar strings like "yyy", "yyyy"..., so it would be useful to have a sanity check as described for the previous regular expression.

Additionally, here's a quick example of how one might use the above to manipulate a single date format string:

```
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now();
String dateFormatString = "dd/MM/yyyy H:m:s";
System.out.println("Old Format: \"" + dateFormatString + "\" = " + 
    date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormatString)));
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:[^My]*)([My]+[^\\w]*[My]+)(?:[^My]*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(dateFormatString);
if(dateFormatString.contains("y") && dateFormatString.contains("M") && m.matches())
{
    dateFormatString = m.group(1);
    System.out.println("New Format: \"" + dateFormatString + "\" = " + 
        date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormatString)));
}
else
{
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Couldn't shorten date format string!");
}
```

**Output:**

> Old Format: "dd/MM/yyyy H:m:s" = 14/08/2019 16:55:45
>   New Format: "MM/yyyy" = 08/2019

Comment: Can you post an example of this actually being used? I'm struggling to visualise how you'd use it.

Comment: @Jakg Can you give an example of what inputs and outputs you might be expecting for your usage? From what I can tell, you're taking an input that is a localized format string, and want to output a localized month-year format string?

Comment: @Jakg I've added an example; hopefully it helps :)

Comment: Thanks! This works well and avoids a loop (at least for the regular expression).

You can easily inject the characters into the regex to parameterize it also.

E.G. ``MessageFormat.format("(?:[^{0}]*)([{0}]+[^\\w]*[{0}]+)(?:[^{0}]*)", new String(charsToRetain))``

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't handle an input of "MMM d, yyyy" - output ``DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM)`` in a UK Locale.

Comment: That is intentional. A d, in the middle of MMMM yyyy is disallowed because d is a word character.

Comment: @Jakg If you allow word characters in the middle, you're going to run into a lot of nasty matches like `yyabbadabbadooMM`. If you do want any inbetween characters to match, you can simply change the `[^\\w]` in the regex to `[^My]`.

Comment: Thanks again for this! I've run into another problem - if you use an input of `d MMM y`, only matching the letter "y", it generates the pattern `(?:[^y]*)([y]+[^y]*[y]+)(?:[^y]*)` - which doesn't match the single-y digit. Any ideas?

Comment: @Jakg If you use the substitution for `y`, you have to realize that `([y]+[^y]*[y]+)` is going to require at least 2 `y`s, optionally separated by non-`y`s. If you want the second `y` group to be optional, you can do that by simply changing the whole substitution expression to: `MessageFormat.format("(?:[^{0}]*)([{0}]+[^\\w]*[{0}]?)(?:[^{0}]*)", new String(charsToRetain))`. It might be a problem with the `[^\\w]*` capturing every non-word character to the right of group 1, so make that reluctant: `MessageFormat.format("(?:[^{0}]*)([{0}]+[^\\w]*?[{0}]?)(?:[^{0}]*)", new String(charsToRetain))`

Comment: Oh, and if you change the `[^\\w]` to `[^{0}]` as you seem to have done, you'll almost certainly have to make the capture reluctant.

Answer (score -2):

I'll try to answer with the understanding of my question : how do I remove from a list/table/array of String, elements that does not exactly follow the patern 'dd/MM'.

so I'm looking for a function that looks like

```
public List<String> removeUnWantedDateFormat(List<String> input)
```

We can expect, from my knowledge on Dateformat, only 4 possibilities that you would want, hoping i dont miss any, which are "MM/yyyy", "MMM/yyyy", "MM/yy", "MM/yyyy". So that we know what we are looking for we can do an easy function.

```
public List<String> removeUnWantedDateFormat(List<String> input) {
  String s1 = "MM/yyyy";
  string s2 = "MMM/yyyy";
  String s3 = "MM/yy";
  string s4 = "MMM/yy";

  for (String format:input) {
    if (!s1.equals(format) && s2.equals(format) && s3.equals(format) && s4.equals(format))
      input.remove(format);
  }
  return input;
}
```

Better not to use regex if you can, it costs a lot of resources. And great improvement would be to use an enum of the date format you accept, like this you have better control over it, and even replace them.

Hope this will help, cheers

edit: after i saw the comment, i think it would be better to use contains instead of equals, should work like a charm and instead of remove,

input = string expected.

so it would looks more like:

```
public List<String> removeUnWantedDateFormat(List<String> input) {
  List<String> comparaisons = new ArrayList<>();
  comparaison.add("MMM/yyyy");
  comparaison.add("MMM/yy");
  comparaison.add("MM/yyyy");
  comparaison.add("MM/yy");

  for (String format:input) {
    for(String comparaison: comparaisons)
      if (format.contains(comparaison)) {
      format = comparaison;
      break;
    }
  }
  return input;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see how this answers my question?

Comment: I'm trying to do this dynamically and not hardcode anything.

Comment: Could you give me an example of what this actually does?

Comment: mhh, yes then i guess my solution is a solution but not to your problem. I just finally understood really the problematic, sorry. I took your exemple as the problem, so my answer is specific in one use case. But then i guess you would not have needed help